# Contract.Requires in exception ctor fails with error CC1027: Malformed contract

Tags: .net, code-contracts

I am trying to write an exception and on the ctor I added a Contract.Requires declaration. for some reason the compilation of this fails with
error CC1027: Malformed contract
I am using the latest version (1.4.60317.12) of code contract addin to VS2012

```
Public NotInheritable Class ValidationException
    Inherits Exception

    Public Property Result() As FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult

    Public Sub New(ByVal ValidateResult As FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult)
        Contract.Requires(Of ArgumentNullException)(ValidateResult IsNot Nothing, "ValidateResult is nothing.")


        Me.Result = ValidateResult
    End Sub

End Class
```

if I remove the Contact.Requires and put

```
        If ValidateResult Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("ValidateResult", "ValidateResult is nothing.")
        End If
        Contract.EndContractBlock()
```

instead compilation works but I get a warning
CC1057: Method 'WindowsApplication1.Data.Validation.ValidationException.#ctor(FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult)' has custom parameter validation but assembly mode is not set to support this. It will be treated as Requires.

which indicates that Requires *is* supported.

is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behaviour - works OK in a method but causes a malformed contract exception  when in the constructor. I see someone else had the same issue (a year ago) and has [posted on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/2e37bd13-f45d-4327-bfb3-85e979d8ea29/). Mike Barnett is awesome, and should be able to fix it if he can get to recreate it.

Comment: thanks for posting on MSDN. I have also subscribed to the thread on MSDN so let's wait and see if an answer is provided.

Comment: Yes, we are having issues with extracting contracts from VB constructors. We have recently fixed some more issues in that area and those fixes will be available in the next release.